# Parseando um XML e seus respectivos XSD

Tags: java, xml, xml-namespaces, xml-schema

Preciso *parsear* um WADL manualmente e criar um XML com especificações que tenho aqui.

Exemplo:

-> Arquivo YahooSearch.wadl

[...]

```
<application
* xmlns:yn="urn:yahoo:yn" *
>
  <grammars>
    <include 
      href="NewsSearchResponse.xsd"/>
    <include
      href="NewsSearchError.xsd"/>
  </grammars>
```

[...]

```
<method name="GET" id="search">
        <request> 
// Aqui há uma requisição com um paramêtro, 
// eu preciso descrever esse parametro no xml posteriormente criado, até aqui OK, dou um jeito
          <param name="appid" type="xsd:string" 
            style="query" required="true"/>
        </request>
        <response status="200"> 
// Aqui há uma resposta do tipo xml,
// aonde o tipo do objeto no conteúdo é um ResultSet,
// que está sendo referenciado lá em cima e descrito logo abaixo
          <representation mediaType="application/xml"
            element="yn:ResultSet"/>
        </response>
</method>
```

-> Arquivo NewsSearchResponse.xsd:

[...]

```
<!-- Preciso inserir esse cara de uma forma mais descritiva no novo XML,
ou seja, preciso parsear esse XSD, existe uma API para facilitar isso, se não tenho que ir pegando nó por nó e ir construindo um elemento ? -->

  <xs:complexType name="ResultType">
<xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="Title" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="Summary" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="Url" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="ClickUrl" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="NewsSource" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="NewsSourceUrl" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="Language" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="PublishDate" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="ModificationDate" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
  <xs:element name="Thumbnail" type="ImageType" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
```

[...]

Qual API me sugerem a usar para o caso acima e sugestões de como fazer?

Comment: Já olhou http://xstream.codehaus.org/ ?
Se xstream nao for flexivel o suficiente pra voce, entao o negocio é resolver tudo com JAXB mesmo.

Comment: Então, o que eu percebi é que eu preciso montar uma classe que vai receber o output do XSD, só que o meu programa vai receber várias WADL diferentes e com XSD diferentes, ou seja eu não sei o output. Sabe me responder se é possivel fazer isso com XSTREAM ou JAXB?

Comment: Uma tradução perfeitamente adequada para _parse_ é *analisar* ou *interpretar*.